# Angular: using promise in service to store data once, cache

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise

I'm trying to use a service to store the data from my API, and only make a call to the API once across different pages. Right now I have a solution working with the controller accessing the service's promise and setting the scope variable in the callback, but I was wondering if there was a way to make this cleaner. I saw in another thread that $http.get returns a promise so there should be a way to make use of that, but when I tried using the answer from yohairosen in the following question, but it didn't set my variable properly:[Use Promise and service together in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332943/use-promise-and-service-together-in-angular)

Here's my code

**/app/scripts/services/team.js**

```
app.factory('Team', function($http, $q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('/api/teams').success(function(teams){
    deferred.resolve(teams);
  });

  return {
    promise: deferred.promise,
  }
});
```

**/app/scripts/controllers/teams.js**

```
app.controller('TeamsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Team) {
  Team.promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.teams = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: it works http://plnkr.co/edit/SHsffFMs1A66H2mk8N1m?p=preview (check the console)

Comment: Yes it works, I was asking if there's a cleaner way to do it, without making a separate promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With promises you can chain `then` calls.

```
app.factory('Team', function($http) {

  return {
    promise: $http.get('/api/teams').then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    })
  }
});
```

This notation is not only shorter, but failures($q.reject) are also propagated.

Comment: Hmm tried it and it's not returning anything from the factory, even though the response.data returns correctly. Here's a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/SkXi9LhE9ROzblZpFSkl?p=preview

Comment: Just need to unwrap the promise in the ctlr: http://plnkr.co/edit/vd7mUmDfgv8lvxTGC5wM?p=preview